# Apache Spark’s Structured Streaming with Google PubSub

Tags: apache-spark, google-cloud-pubsub, spark-structured-streaming

I'm using Spark Dstream to pull and process data from Google PubSub.

I'm looking for a way to move to structured streaming but still using Pub/Sub.

Also, I should mention that my messages are Snappy compressed in Pub/Sub.

I found [this](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/bigdata-interop/issues/84) issue which claims that using Pub/Sub with structured streaming is not supported.

Is someone has encountered this problem? Is it possible to implement custom Receiver to read the data from Pub/Sub

Thanks

Comment: how did you solve it? is there a work around?

Comment: @PatoNavarro We moved from Pub/Sub to Kafka, so I didn't need to solve it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [feature request](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/bigdata-interop/issues/84) you referenced is still accurate: Cloud Pub/Sub does not have the concept of an offset to track your read position, so structured streaming with Cloud Pub/Sub is not supported.

Comment: any news about structured streaming in pubsub? Thanks

Comment: Structured streaming is not currently supported. If you're interested in this feature, we'd be interested in learning more about your use case. Please suggest it as a feature request here: https://googlecloudplatform.uservoice.com/forums/302631-cloud-pub-sub