# GCP: Spark Structured Streaming + Custom Pub/Sub Source

Tags: apache-spark, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub, spark-structured-streaming

There is currently no support for a PubSub source in Spark Structured Streaming.

Has anyone wrote a custom source in Spark Structured Streaming to read from PubSub?

Is this a possible approach?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Apache Spark’s Structured Streaming with Google PubSub](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55964723/apache-spark-s-structured-streaming-with-google-pubsub)