# Google Cloud Pub/Sub - Spark structured streaming support

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-pubsub, google-cloud-dataproc

Came across below two references, where it was mentioned that pub/sub does not support spark structured streaming.

- [Apache Spark’s Structured Streaming with Google PubSub](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55964723/apache-spark-s-structured-streaming-with-google-pubsub)
- https://github.com/GoogleCloudDataproc/hadoop-connectors/issues/84

Pub/Sub Lite appears to provide support for Spark Structured Streaming - https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/data-analytics/pubsub-lites-apache-spark-structured-streaming-connector-is-now-generally-available

Additionally , databricks supports structured streaming with pub/sub as input as per - https://docs.databricks.com/structured-streaming/pub-sub.html

Question: I would like to clarify whether Google Cloud Pub/Sub (not Pub/Sub Lite) supports Spark Structured Streaming, if we are running spark on dataproc?